# Ajax chat messages repeating rather than just updating

Tags: javascript, ajax, chat

Now I'm making my own chat system, thing (practice). Everything is working bar one bit. When I enter a new message, ever message in the database is added again instead of just updating the existing log.

For example the log:

```
9th-Apr dunkirk: come a bit closer  16:57
```

Then I'll add another message saying TOO FAR! and it will update, but it'll repeat such like:

```
9th-Apr dunkirk: come a bit closer  16:57
9th-Apr dunkirk: come a bit closer  16:57 <--repeating everything again
9th-Apr dunkirk: TOO FAR!   16:58
```

There's a fair amount of code so I'll only include the offending piece (as far as I can see):

```
function updateMessages(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
            try{
                xmlText = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                messages = xmlText.getElementsByTagName('messages');
                for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    time = '<td>'+messages[i].getElementsByTagName('time')[0].innerHTML+'</td>';
                    date = '<td>'+messages[i].getElementsByTagName('date')[0].innerHTML+'</td>';
                    username = '<td>'+messages[i].getElementsByTagName('username')[0].innerHTML+'</td>';
                    message = '<td>'+messages[i].getElementsByTagName('message')[0].innerHTML+'</td>';
                    text = date+username+message+time;

                    tr = document.createElement('tr');      
                    tr.innerHTML = text;
                    document.getElementById('chatMessages').appendChild(tr);
                };
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I'd like it to show all messages, without repeating, but still updating when a new message is met, like most chats.

I had a similar issue before with the registration system which I fixed with a while loop, but that fix didn't seem to work in this instance. Said previous fix was:

```
        while (update.firstChild) {
            update.removeChild(update.firstChild);
        }
```

Checking if the parent had a child, if not continue, if so, delete the child.

I'm sure the solution is incredibly simple regarding the initial text creation, but as you can likely tell I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Does your response only contain the new messages since your last call? Or does it contain all the messages?

Comment: In this example it would still contain the two unique messages, no repeats.

Comment: Well it seems that each time you receive a message you are appending all the messages onto the chat log. However what you would need to do is only append those that are in `messages` and not already in the log

Comment: Are you positive that the server is not returning back all the messages? `console.dir(xmlText);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are always appending the entire chat log onto your messages, rather than just those new messages. So you need to keep a log of messages you've seen, and only insert new messages if they haven't yet been added.

```
// at the start of your script
var chatLog = {};

// --- SNIP ---

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  time = '<td>' + messages[i].getElementsByTagName('time')[0].innerHTML + '</td>';
  date = '<td>' + messages[i].getElementsByTagName('date')[0].innerHTML + '</td>';
  username = '<td>' + messages[i].getElementsByTagName('username')[0].innerHTML + '</td>';
  message = '<td>' + messages[i].getElementsByTagName('message')[0].innerHTML + '</td>';
  text = date + username + message + time;

  if (!chatLog[text]) {
    continue; // don't add the message to the chat as it already exists
  }

  tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById('chatMessages').appendChild(tr);
  chatLog[text] = true; // mark that we've already added this message
};
```

You could also always clear the table before adding messages, but this way you avoid un-neccesary DOM inserts (at the cost of a bit more memory).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have table element in html code.
Lets say its id is **chatTable**.

add following before for loop

document.getElementById("chatTable").innerHTML = "";

I think this should work.